# How can I join two tables with different keys based on date values?

Tags: sql, pyspark, left-join

I have two tables, table Y, with composite Primary key `OmgevingId, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID, DienstverbandID, VerloningsNummer`:

| OmgevingID | KantoorID | WerkgeverID | DienstverbandID | VerloningsNummer | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 2 | 2023-02-01 |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 3 | 2023-03-01 |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 4 | 2023-01-01 |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 5 | 2023-02-01 |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 6 | 2023-03-01 |

and table X, with composite Primary Key `OmgevingId, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID, DienstverbandID, WerktijdID`:

| OmgevingID | KantoorID | WerkgeverID | DienstverbandID | WerktijdID | StartDate | EndDate | FieldINeed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 1 | 2019-12-28 | 2021-02-02 | A |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 2 | 2021-02-03 | 2023-01-31 | B |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 3 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-15 | C |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 1 | 2019-01-31 | NULL | D |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 1 | 2018-12-28 | 2020-02-02 | E |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 2 | 2020-02-03 | 2022-01-31 | F |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 3 | 2022-02-01 | NULL | G |

I want to `LEFT JOIN` table X into table Y. However, this leads to problems as there is a `m:n` relationship, and a `LEFT JOIN` will make the resulting table explode. As you can see, the tables have mutual keys: `OmgevingID, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID and DienstverbandID`. If I could somehow make it so that these keys uniquely identify a row in table X, my problem would be solved as there would be a `m:1` relationship between Y and X, and I could therefore safely join X into Y.

I could do this by for example using a `GROUP BY` on the mutual keys in table X, and taking some aggregate of WerktijdID and the rows behind WerktijdID. I could then `INNER JOIN` this table on table X, to get a table with only one 'werktijdID' per combination of `OmgevingID, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID and DienstverbandID`, thus making the resulting Primary Key of this table `OmgevingID, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID, DienstverbandID`. Then I could safely join X into Y. The following code snippet shows how such a query would look (For simplicity I only included keys in the query but similar logic could be applied to other data fields):

```
SELECT x.*, wt.* FROM
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT OmgevingID, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID, DienstverbandID, WerktijdID
    FROM y
    INNER JOIN (
           SELECT OmgevingID, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID, PersoonID, DienstverbandID, MAX(WerktijdID) as werktijdID
           FROM Y
           GROUP BY OmgevingID, AdministratieKantoorID, WerkgeverID, DienstverbandID) maxwt
    ON y.OmgevingID = maxwt.OmgevingID
        AND y.AdministratieKantoorID = maxwt.AdministratieKantoorID
        AND y.WerkgeverID = maxwt.WerkgeverID
        AND y.DienstverbandID = maxwt.DienstverbandID
        AND y.WerktijdID = maxwt.WerktijdID ) as wt
ON x.OmgevingID = wt.OmgevingID
AND x.AdministratieKantoorID = wt.AdministratieKantoorID
AND x.WerkgeverID = wt.WerkgeverID
AND x.DienstverbandID = wt.DienstverbandID
```

The results of such a query would look like this:

| OmgevingID | KantoorID | WerkgeverID | DienstverbandID | VeloningsNummer | Period | WerktijdID | StartDate | EndDate | FieldINeed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 3 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-15 | C |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 2 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2019-01-31 | NULL | D |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 3 | 2023-03-01 | 3 | 2022-02-01 | NULL | G |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 4 | 2023-01-01 | 3 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-15 | C |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 5 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2019-01-31 | NULL | D |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 6 | 2023-03-01 | 3 | 2022-02-01 | NULL | G |

But that would be incorrect, as I don't want to have the `MAX(WerktijdID)`, instead I want the WerktijdID which is "active" in a certain period. Only one WerktijdID can be active at a given time in table X. To find which WerktijdID is "active" in a certain Period, I can use the following rule: `StartDate <= Period AND (EndDate >= Period OR EndDate is NULL)`

The (correct) expected result of the query would look as follows:

| OmgevingID | KantoorID | WerkgeverID | DienstverbandID | VeloningsNummer | Period | WerktijdID | StartDate | EndDate | FieldINeed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2 | 2021-02-03 | 2023-01-31 | B |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 2 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2019-01-31 | NULL | D |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 3 | 2023-03-01 | 3 | 2022-02-01 | NULL | G |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 243 | 4 | 2023-01-01 | 2 | 2021-02-03 | 2023-01-31 | B |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 244 | 5 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 2019-01-31 | NULL | D |
| 28 | 1 | 19 | 245 | 6 | 2023-03-01 | 3 | 2022-02-01 | NULL | G |

However, when I try this in SQL like so:

```
SELECT x.*, y.* FROM y
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM x
    WHERE StartDate <= y.Period AND (EndDate >= y.Period OR EndDate is NULL) as x_alias 
ON y.OmgevingID = x_alias.OmgevingID 
AND y.AdministratieKantoorID = x_alias.AdministratieKantoorID
AND y.WerkgeverID = x_alias.WerkgeverID 
AND y.DienstverbandID = x_alias.DienstverbandID
```

I get the following error: `"Error: Column 'x_alias.Period' does not exist"`. I think this is because I cannot refer to y.period inside the subquery? Any tips on how to achieve my desired result would be greatly appreciated. I am using Spark-SQL, so a solution in PySpark would also be acceptable.

Comment: You have no table x outside the derived table (FROM clause subquery), you can only SELECT x_alias columns.

Comment: And, as you have noted, you can't reference y columns inside the subquery. A LATERAL derived table solves that problem, but I don't know if it's supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't refer to the outer table (y) in a subquery,

Try this :

```
SELECT x.*, y.* 
FROM y
LEFT JOIN x
ON y.OmgevingID = x.OmgevingID 
AND y.AdministratieKantoorID = x.AdministratieKantoorID
AND y.WerkgeverID = x.WerkgeverID 
AND y.DienstverbandID = x.DienstverbandID
AND x.StartDate <= y.Period 
AND (x.EndDate >= y.Period OR x.EndDate IS NULL)
```